# Onclick button crashes application

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I'm adding a button that returns the user to the home screen upon clicking it however the application does a force close every time I click the button.

[Source Code](https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yiU8UoHU3bXXWaIIk1LwwGP-EMiQ9l1gPY3qQz-djhQ/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1yiU8UoHU3bXXWaIIk1LwwGP-EMiQ9l1gPY3qQz-djhQ/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: post your logcat trace

Comment: and post the _relevant_ parts of your code inline in your question.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are getting NPE.

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);  <<<<Error is here NPE

Intent intent = new Intent();
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);  <<<There must be Compile time error because you did not declare homeIntent
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(homeIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

For what I see I think that your problem is here:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
Notification noti = new Notification.Builder(this)
.setTicker("Ticker Title")
.setContentTitle("Content Title")
.setContentText("Notifcation Content")
.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher)
.setContentIntent(pIntent).getNotification();
noti.flags=Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notificationManager.notify(0, noti);


Intent intent = new Intent();
Intent intent=new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
homeIntent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
homeIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
startActivity(homeIntent);
}
```

and more accurate the intent in this line:

```
PendingIntent pIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, intent, 0);
```

you are trying to add this intent to the `PendingIntent` before you actually created it.

and what is the `homeIntent` you are using?